# Receiving and error for https in react-native

Tags: http, react-native, https

I am receiving the following error message:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module 'http' from
'some/path/to/iugu.js': Module 'http' does not exist in the Haste module map
```

I'm following this documentation for using iugu:

https://github.com/iugu/iugu-node

```
var iugu = require('iugu')(
 'fa484a7c14ff046c6f1c589d2f0c389b',
  'latest'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

That module is not fully compatible with React Native.

Some node modules are automatically available via require() like http, crypto, etc. These modules are available in Node, but they are not automatically available in other environments such as browsers and in this case React Native.

To use your package seems that you need to include a compatible `http` implementation.

There are some ways to kind of "Nativeify" those modules and to include those node core libraries in React Native. Take a look to [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify) and also this article [Using Core Node JS Modules in React Native Apps](https://hackernoon.com/using-core-node-js-modules-in-react-native-apps-64acd4d07140).